# Thumbs down NavigationController-left and right view scrolls from rootViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, navigationcontroller

I am newbie ios developer from Turkiye. So excuse me for my eng.
I want to learn how can do this on NavigationController?

*****LeftSideControllerView -----RootControllerView-----RightSideControllerView*****

I want scroll like this? is it impossible? how should I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in the following way.

1.Create a NavigationController with LeftSideControllerView.

```
LeftSideControllerView *firstVC = [[LeftSideControllerView alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];
```

2.Create the Center View Controller and push it to the navigation controller (without the animation).

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondVC animated:NO];
```

Here SecondViewController is the RootControllerView you specified in your question.

3.From the SecondViewController you can push the RightSideControllerView.

This is one way of doing it, but may not be the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be having a UIScrollView with a width of three times the screen, and enable paging, so it feels like the homescreen. Then have three UIViews in each segment of the UISCrollView which correspond to LeftSideControllerView, MiddleControllerView, and RightSideControllerView. Note: You may have to make a new new for the middle, because the RooControllerView will handle the large UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

NAvigation will so only one view controller in the view. It always starts with Root View Controller.

One way for doing your scenario is make the LeftViewController as RootViewController.in the next line push the secondviewcontroller which u like to have as a visible viewcontroller at the begining. then push the Rightviewconteoller whenever u need. To make the left viewcontroller use poptorootviewcontroller method.

the second way is Push the Leftviewcontroller by using the property animated no.

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:Leftviewcontroller animated:NO];

use ur custom animation like leftviewcontroller moves from the left.